# Play the m4v video file in background ie only sound

Tags: android, media-player, m4v, audio-player

Im trying to play a m4v files audio alone in the background.

I tried using `SoundPool` and it is giving me error while loading it from the raw folder.

i used this [sample program](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/11/play-audio-resources-using-soundpool.html).

```
10-27 11:49:11.684: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1484): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File Hello World, AudioPlayerActivity! from drawable resource ID #0x7f040000
10-27 11:49:11.684: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1484):     at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:860)
10-27 11:49:11.684: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1484):     at   android.media.SoundPool.load(SoundPool.java:204)
10-27 11:49:11.684: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1484):     at com.sample.audio.AudioPlayerActivity.onCreate(AudioPlayerActivity.java:31)
10-27 11:49:11.684: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1484):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
10-27 11:49:11.684: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1484):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
10-27 11:49:11.684: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1484):     ... 11 more
```

But i can able to play the file using `VideoView` but i need only audio.

I dont know how to play the m4v file in the soundpool or some way i need to play in the background.
How to achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all take a look at [supported media formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) page. I've not see m4v format but if it works with you see below.

I don't know how to use `SoundPool` but if you want to use it I suggest you to extrapolate a supported audio format from your video with an encoder.

Finally I can suggest you a solution with VideoView (since you say that the video works). In your main.xml put this to refer your `VideoView`

```
<VideoView
   android:id="@+id/video"
   android:layout_width="0.1px"
   android:layout_height="0.1px">
</VideoView>
```

And use this code in your `onCreate` method of your Activity:

```
String uri = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.videoname;
VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));
video.start();
```

I've tried it myself and it works. I know that this is a *bad* way to get the audio in background but if you haven't any other solution I think that this is sufficient.